# Deleting a node from a linked list LUT?

Tags: java, memory-management, linked-list

We are trying to write a method to delete a node with a particular key from a linked list implementation of a LUT.

Summary of the code I wrote:

```
public void delete (String k) {

    Node currNode = listHead;
    Node prevNode = listHead;

    Key key = new Key (k);

    while (!currNode.key.equals(k) && currNode != null){
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode.next;
    }

    if (currNode == listHead) {
      listHead = listHead.next;
    } else {
      prevNode.next = currNode.next;
    }
}
```

My friend wrote essentially the same thing but didn't use a previous node pointer, and instead wrote as his last line:

```
currNode = currNode.next //detach point, override
```

Are both of these equivalent?  I think what I'm confused about it Java memory management.
If you have already created your `listHead` Node somewhere else, and you write:

```
Node currNode = listHead;
```

`currNode` is only storing a reference to the memory location where `listHead` is stored, right?  So in the while-loop when you do `currNode = currNode.next`, what you're doing is going to the memory location referenced in `currNode` and looking at the variable next and storing the reference to that memory location in `currNode`?  So basically updating where `currNode` is pointing to.  This would mean that my friend's code was wrong , right?  Since his code would similarly mean: "update the reference currently in `currNode` with the memory location of `currNode.next`".

Would someone mind helping me remove the fog please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You friend's can't be right because one has to change the `.next` field of a `Node` to delete a `Node` from the list.

As I imagine you know, to delete node `N` from a list you need set the `.next` field of node `N-1` to refer to node `N+1`.  Your friend's approach can't possibly be doing that because it's not changing any node's `.next` field.

As for memory, once `N-1`'s `.next` field refers to `N+1`, then `N` is no longer being kept alive by the list.  Whether or not it is eligible for garbage collection depends on if anything else in the program has a reference to it.  But the list has now washed its hands of it.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the correct answer to your query, but you have a couple bugs in your code that won't fit into a comment.

**`NullPointerException`**

Your `while` loop condition is backwards. It should be

```
while (currNode != null && !currNode.key.equals(k)) { ... }
```

to avoid a `NullPointerException` when you reach the end of the list or if the list has no nodes to begin with.

**Value not found**

The method doesn't handle the case where `k` is not contained in the list. You need to check `currNode` for `null` after the while loop.

```
if (currNode != null) {
    if (currNode == listHead)
        listHead = listHead.next;
    else
        prevNode.next = currNode.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct -- your friend's code won't actually remove the node from the list.

I think stepping through your code with a debugger might help clear the fog. If you're not already using an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), I'd recommend IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, or Netbeans -- all of them include a debugger.